# Synchronous hold of a specific code in an asynchronous method in c #

Tags: c#, asynchronous, queue, task-queue

Note : i used language translate

I filter and return cached data in a method in the api system I use in C #. If there is no data in the cache, I pull it from the database asynchronously. If there is no data in the cache, the bidders coming to the api at the same time crush each other in asynchronous code. So the first requester must be the first to pull the data, others should wait for the first requester to pull the data. The code I wrote:

```
[HttpPost]
public ... GetPersonels(...)
{

  var list = caching.Get<...>([CacheName]);

  if (list is null)
  {
     System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(InsertCacheForGetPersonels);
  }
  
  ...

  return [Filtred Personels];
}

protected void InsertCacheForGetPersonels()
{
    //HERE !!!
    //what should i do here ?
    //HERE !!!
    if (caching.Get<...>([CacheName]) is null)
    {
        var list = GetPersonelList();

        caching.Set(list, [CacheName], Indefinite());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a queue that will execute InsertCacheForGetPersonels() one by one in order they come in.

Because I noticed that you are already using Task Factory, I recommend that you check out this Microsoft example regarding using Task Scheduler and Task Factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the link. I did such a class. Do i have it wrong ?

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0

```
    public class QueueTasker
    {
        public LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts;
        public List<Task> tasks;
        public TaskFactory factory;
        public CancellationTokenSource cts;
        public object lockObj;
        private static QueueTasker _instance;
        private QueueTasker()
        {
            lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
            tasks = new List<Task>();
            factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            lockObj = new object();
        }
        public static QueueTasker Instance()
        {
            if (_instance is null)
                _instance = new QueueTasker();
            return _instance;
        }
        public Task Add(Action action)
        {
            var task = factory.StartNew(action, cts.Token);
            tasks.Add(task);
            return task;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ```
if (list is null)
   lock (QueueTasker.Instance().lockObj)
       QueueTasker.Instance().Add(() => InsertCacheForSelect(CacheControlType.Insert));
```
Using it that way it worked